# Error: unknown directive "rtmp_stat" (NGNIX fails when using NOALBS .conf file)

Tags: linux, nginx, raspberry-pi, rtmp

I've never used Linux or Raspberry Pi before but I bought one in order to create my own RTMP server. I made one with NGINX and got it working. Now I'm trying to incorporate [NOALBS](https://github.com/715209/nginx-obs-automatic-low-bitrate-switching) for more functionality. I renamed my working .conf to nginx-old.conf and copied in the NOALBS .conf and now NGINX fails with this error.

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "rtmp_stat" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:26
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My .conf is as follows:

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    directio 512;
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ignore_invalid_headers on;
    log_format compression '';

    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name localhost;

        # This URL provides RTMP statistics in XML
        location /stat {
            if ($request_method = "GET") {
                add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"  *;
            }

            rtmp_stat all;

            # Use this stylesheet to view XML as web page
            # in browser
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet /stat.xsl;
        }

        location /stat.xsl {
            # XML stylesheet to view RTMP stats.
            # Copy stat.xsl wherever you want
            # and put the full directory path here
            # root /path/to/stat.xsl/;
            root /var/www/html/stat.xsl;

        }

        location /control {
            rtmp_control all;
        }
    }
}

rtmp {
    log_format compression '';

    server {
        listen 1935;
        ping 30s;
        notify_method get;
        chunk_size 8192;
        ack_window 8192;
        sync 4ms;
        interleave on;
        access_log logs/rtmp-access.log compression;

        # Stream to "rtmp://IPHERE/publish/live".
        application publish {
            live on;
            wait_video on;
            wait_key on;
            exec_options on;
            publish_notify on;
            play_restart on;
            drop_idle_publisher 4s;
            idle_streams off;
            sync 4ms;
            interleave on;
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I've edited is actually adding the stat.xsl path and my Pi's IP address (which I've scrubbed here). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Add this header :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
```